# Jquery click event to add/remove particular class when having multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I am trying to add the functionality of removing the play button once clicked and video starts playing. My problem is that I have multiple videos on the page, and once a play button is clicked and the video stars playing, all other buttons are removed as well.

CODE:

```js
//JS - To remove image overlay and video starts playing (working)

$(function() {
  document.getElementById("playbutton").disabled = true;
  var player = $('iframe');
  var playerOrigin = '*';
  // Listen for messages from the player
  if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
  } else {
  window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
  }

  function onMessageReceived(event) {
  var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  console.log(data.event);
  if (data.event === "ready") {
  //attach ready function to the image
  document.getElementById("playbutton").disabled = false;

  $('#playbutton').click(function() {
    player[0].contentWindow.postMessage({
      "method": "play"
    }, playerOrigin);
    $(this).remove();
   });
   }
 }
});



$('.overlay').click(function() {
$('.video-icon').fadeToggle(300)
})
```

```html
<div id="showreel">
    <div id="container">
        <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
            <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/..."</iframe>
            <img class="overlay" src="../images/overlay.png" style ="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;width: 100%;height:100%" id="playbutton">
        </div>
        <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
        </img>
        <img class="video-icon" src="../../images/general/play-button.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is using IDs uniquely for elements. If you have more than one element with the same ID, you start to run into problems like this (no pun intended).

Try changing your `id="playbutton"` to `class="playbutton"` for all of your play buttons, then change `$('#playbutton').click(function() {` to `$('.playbutton').click(function() {`.